# Persistent Cookies in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to create persistent cookie using javascript but I am not sure how to use domain attribute of the document.cookie.

The domain that I am working on is development environment and it can have special or encrypted characters (%sdf#ed). There is no (.com) in the url.
Example of domain/url: - http://Networkportnumber/talkeasy/%sdf#ed/#1

So I want to create a persistent cookie for the url contains a word "talkeasy"

What I have so far

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = "Tab=" + cookieValue + ";" + expires;
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to use the domain attribute? By default, the cookie is associated with the domain of the web page. You only need to use that attribute if you need to associate it with a parent domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use path when setting cookies.
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";